# Android AdMob ad does not come up most of the time

Tags: android, admob

I have a AdMob banndr ad on my mobile app.  Most of the time it does not come up.  Is this the way it works, or did I do something wrong in setting it up?
Ted

Comment: Accept some answers to your questions and you might get better responses...

Answer (score 1):

If there is no ad to display then an ad is not returned. If you login to your account on admob, in the table that lists your apps there will be a fill rate percentage. That shows what percentage or your requests return ads.

Accept answers to your previous questions.